# sum multiple count expressions in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, sum

I have a column that contain a count expression :

```
=IIF(isnothing(Fields!SuiteNameFR.Value) and Count(Fields!ModuleNameFr.Value) <> 0 , Count(Fields!ModuleNameFr.Value),"")
```

and an other column that contain a count expression also :

```
 =IIF(IsNothing(Fields!SuiteNameFR.Value) ,"" , CountDistinct(Fields!PackageID.Value))
```

I want to sum this tow columns, any help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference objects in the report with expressions using the [ReportItems collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255285.aspx). So you can add the two text boxes together like this:

```
=CInt(ReportItems!TextBox1.Value) + CInt(ReportItems!TextBox2.Value)
```

You can find the name of the report objects by selecting them in the designer and looking at the properties pane.

Comment: I got this error : Warning 1 [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox88.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: Le format de la chaîne d'entrée est incorrect.